# Clearing down folders

Tags: powershell

I'm having an issue getting this script to work as I need it to. I can have it clear down folders if they have the same name but I am trying to get it to clear down all sub folders as well. Having a bit of trouble. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
$baseLocation = "C:\Shares"
$workingDir = "C:\Logs\"
$transcriptFilePath = $workingDir + "SystemScripts\"
$fileDate = Get-Date -format yyyyMMdd
$transcriptFile = $transcriptFilePath+"Files-_Transcript"+$fileDate+".txt"
$nDays = (Get-Date).AddDays(-60)
# Build list of paths to include in cleardown process
$pathsExcludeSubfolders = (Get-ChildItem C:\Shares\Files???Test\Imports\*\ -Directory `
    | Select-Object @{ n= 'Folder'; e = { Convert-Path $_.PSPath } } ).Folder

$pathsExcludeSubfolders += (Get-ChildItem C:\Shares\Files???Test\Exports\*\ -Directory `
    | Select-Object @{ n= 'Folder'; e = { Convert-Path $_.PSPath } } ).Folder

$pathsExcludeSubfolders += (Get-ChildItem C:\Shares\Files???Live\Imports\*\ -Directory `
    | Select-Object @{ n= 'Folder'; e = { Convert-Path $_.PSPath } } ).Folder

$pathsExcludeSubfolders += (Get-ChildItem C:\Shares\Files???Live\Exports\*\ -Directory `
    | Select-Object @{ n= 'Folder'; e = { Convert-Path $_.PSPath } } ).Folder
    
$pathsIncludeSubfolders += (Get-ChildItem C:\Shares\Files???Test\Imports\Backup\*\ -Directory `
    | Select-Object @{ n= 'Folder'; e = { Convert-Path $_.PSPath } } ).Folder

$pathsIncludeSubfolders += (Get-ChildItem C:\Shares\Files???Test\Exports\Backup\*\ -Directory `
    | Select-Object @{ n= 'Folder'; e = { Convert-Path $_.PSPath } } ).Folder

$pathsIncludeSubfolders += (Get-ChildItem C:\Shares\Files???Live\Imports\Backup\*\ -Directory `
    | Select-Object @{ n= 'Folder'; e = { Convert-Path $_.PSPath } } ).Folder

$pathsIncludeSubfolders += (Get-ChildItem C:\Shares\Files???Live\Exports\Backup\*\ -Directory `
    | Select-Object @{ n= 'Folder'; e = { Convert-Path $_.PSPath } } ).Folder

# Check path exist for transcript logging
If(!(Test-Path $transcriptFilePath))
{
    New-Item -Path "C:\Logs\SystemScripts" -ItemType Directory
    
    Start-Transcript -Path $transcriptFile -Append
}
Else
{
    Start-Transcript -Path $transcriptFile -Append
}

# Cleardown log files older than $nDays
foreach($pathInclude in $pathsIncludeSubfolders){

"Clearing $($pathInclude)"
    DeleteItems $pathInclude $nDays $true
}

foreach($pathExclude in $pathsExcludeSubfolders){

"Clearing $($pathExclude)"
    DeleteItems $pathExclude $nDays $false
}

Stop-Transcript
```

The results is this - it seems to try to combine C:\Shares\Files155Live\Imports\Backup\Newcastle with C:\Shares\Files999Live\Exports\Backup\Tyneside instead of just looking for both.

Transcript started, output file is C:\Logs\SystemScripts\sCloud-Files-Cleardown_Transcript20231113.txt
Clearing C:\Shares\Files155Live\Imports\Backup\NewcastleC:\Shares\Files999Live\Exports\Backup\Tyneside
Set-Location : Cannot find path
'C:\Shares\Files155Live\Imports\Backup\NewcastleC:\Shares\Files999Live\Exports\Backup\Tyneside' because it does not
exist.
At C:\scripts\sCloud_AXISNT_Cleardown.ps1:50 char:9

- ```
      Set-Location $folderPath
  ```
- ```
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Shares\Files...Backup\Tyneside:String) [Set-Location], ItemNotFoun
    dException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand

Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path
'C:\Shares\Files155Live\Imports\Backup\NewcastleC:\Shares\Files999Live\Exports\Backup' because it does not exist.
At C:\scripts\sCloud_AXISNT_Cleardown.ps1:52 char:3

- ```
      Get-ChildItem -Path $folderPath -Recurse -Force `
  ```
- ```
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Shares\Files...Exports\Backup:String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotFou
    ndException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Clearing C:\Shares\Files032Test\Imports\Backup
Clearing C:\Shares\Files999Test\Imports\Backup
Clearing C:\Shares\Files032Test\Exports\Backup
Clearing C:\Shares\Files999Test\Exports\Backup
Clearing C:\Shares\Files155Live\Imports\Backup
Clearing C:\Shares\Files155Live\Imports\Newcastle
Clearing C:\Shares\Files999Live\Imports\Backup
Clearing C:\Shares\Files155Live\Exports\Backup
Clearing C:\Shares\Files999Live\Exports\Backup
Clearing C:\Shares\Files999Live\Exports\Tyneside

Tried removing + from some lines but results vary with some folders being ignored still.

Comment: What does it mean to "clear down" a folder?

Comment: Sorry, basically the script removes any files in any directory that is older than 60 days.

Comment: And you want to remove any empty folders left behind after deleting the files? Or is the folder hierarchy to stay in place?

Comment: The folder hierarchy must stay, so only the files yes

Answer (score 2):

This is likely a type confusion issue - the first assignment to `$pathsExcludeSubfolders` may result in a single string being assigned, after which the `+=` operator will perform string concatenation (rather than adding to an array).

Use the `@(...)` array subexpression operator to ensure the first value assigned is an array, after which `+=` will work as expected:

```
$pathsExcludeSubfolders = @(Get-ChildItem C:\Shares\Files???Test\Imports\*\ -Directory |Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName)
```

Another option is to collect all the directory items in a single subexpression and then grabbing the full path from each afterwards:

```
$pathsExcludeSubfolders = @(
    Get-ChildItem C:\Shares\Files???Test\Exports\*\ -Directory 
    Get-ChildItem C:\Shares\Files???Live\Exports\*\ -Directory 
    Get-ChildItem C:\Shares\Files???Test\Exports\Backup\*\ -Directory 
    Get-ChildItem C:\Shares\Files???Live\Exports\Backup\*\ -Directory
) |Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
```

Comment: Excellent, both options have worked great, thank you